# Code-signing application from different locations

Tags: windows, .net

In our company, one of the software group is using a certificate from a trusted provider to sign their drivers manually on their local machine. My group wants to start to sign our installers and some administrator tools and we would like to use the same certificate.

The problem is each group is using its own build machine where the signing will need to be done.

I'm not an expert with certification and I'm not sure what is the best approach and if it is possible to do it:

1) Install the certificate on each build machine. I guess it is not recommanded because your certificate could be compromise more easily since it is located at more than one place.
2) Install the certificate on a server and each build machine call it to sign their own binaries.

or something else?

Note: Our infrastructure is on Windows.

Comment: It very much depends on your workflow and the company. Besides servers I think your major concerns revolve around Security (which would be better ansewered by the security SE) or by the culture of trust around your development team which should be in the programmers SE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part is the *private key* to which the certificate is linked. Unfortunately, some widely deployed documentations get it wrong and call "certificate" what really is the union of the certificate itself (which contains the public key and is entirely public) and the corresponding private key (which had better *not* be public, of course).

In order to keep the private key private, it is best *not* to copy it in many places. When a private key "travels" between computers, it is normally as a [PKCS#12 archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF12) (previously known as "PFX"), which contains the certificate and the private key, and is password-protected. The entropy of this password is crucial for the security of this *transit*, but, of course, this protects only the key as it is transferred. You are right: the more a private key is copied, the more vulnerable to theft it becomes.

The **normal way** of doing this is the following:

- Each build machine has its own *development* certificate. Development certificates are certificates which you generate yourself, with a custom CA (which can be some crude usage of the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) command-line tool). Test machines, on which development is performed, are configured to accept this custom CA as trusted (or maybe signature checks are deactivated altogether).
- For **production releases**, the binaries which are to be signed are transported to a specific, protected machine which contains the real signature key (the one corresponding to the certificate that you bought from the "trusted provider"). Releases don't occur often, so this manual procedure should be acceptable.

Having a free-for-all signature system, accessible and routinely accessed by developers, looks somewhat dangerous to me. A signature with a key which is trusted by third parties is a *responsibility*: it makes you liable. You should strive to sign things with that key at rarely as possible, i.e. only for releases.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to put the signing certificate on the developer's machine, it's significantly safer to NOT do so.

Ideally the signing key should be encrypted such that a password must be manually typed by someone who actually inspects what he's signing to verify that it's legitimate. And any machine that has access to the key should *NOT* have direct or indirect access to the Internet. No network at all.

A lot can be learned by reading about the code signing mistakes of others.

- [Adobe: Inappropriate Use of Adobe Code Signing Certificate](http://blogs.adobe.com/asset/2012/09/inappropriate-use-of-adobe-code-signing-certificate.html)
- [Opera: Hackers pilfered code-signing certificate to sign malware](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security/opera-hackers-pilfered-code-signing-certificate-sign-malware-221644)
- [Security Firm Bit9 Hacked, Used to Spread Malware](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2013/02/security-firm-bit9-hacked-used-to-spread-malware/)